# Finding the intersection of two functions

Tags: python, math, equation-solving

I have two equations: one linear and one exponential, and I need to find where they intersect. They are of the form:

```
y1 = a * x
y2 = b * exp(c * x) + d
```

where the variables a, b, c and d are known.

I've tried looking online for solutions to find `y1=y2`, and `y1-y2=0`, but with no result. Are there any simple ways of solving these equations using Python?

```
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol

a = 2.06233087 
b = -0.41000778  
c = 0.44198402
d = 0.1251175917215428

x = Symbol('x', real=True)

result = sympy.solvers.solve(a*sympy.exp(b*x)+c-d*x, x)
```

Currently, I am trying to solve it with sympy solvers, but the equation above makes my computer 'crash'.

Comment: There are several equation solving tools for Python.  They should all be able to minimize `abs(f1(x)-f2(x))`.

Comment: I think you could use SymPy. Can't remember how to do it off the top of my head though. You'll probably find it here: [Solvers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

Comment: Steven, after you read the SymPy solvers documentation, please post an answer, separate from your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: So far, the Sympy solvers seem to be crashing in my case. Maybe my equation is too long or something.

Comment: I don't think that this equation can be solved in closed-form, though for any specific choice of `a` etc. you can solve it numerically.

Comment: Do you need numerical or analytical solution?

Comment: @JohnColeman The solution of equation involves lambert's W-function.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Good to know, but if that is the case one would think that `SymPy` could handle it.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, sympy solves that as `-LambertW(-b*c*exp(c*d/a)/a)/c + d/a`.

Comment: @StevenBijl For me sympy keeps running for ~15 minutes producing no results. I have built graphs of both functions and found that they have a single point of intersection with approximate coordinates `(x = -0.127, y = -0.262)`.

Comment: @StevenBijl BTW you have different equations. From the text of your post `b * exp(c * x) + d - a*x) and in the code `a * exp(b * x) + c - d*x, x`

Comment: Use `nsolve` instead of `solve`.